# Integrating Pusher with Laravel and Ionic 1( AngularJS) in chat app

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, chat, pusher

I'm trying to set up a chat application with the following stack (Laravel, AngularJS, Ionic, Pusher)
I'm using AngularJS v1.6.x and Laravel 5.3 (which has already Pusher integrated with it per default) 
So I followed the docs to create a pusher account, and set up an Event in laravel with broadcasting and everything, and in the front-end (Ionic side) I have to add Pusher, which made me a bit confused since in pretty much all the tutorials they mentioned using Laravel Echo or Redis/Socket.IO

So my question how can I make this architecture work from the AngularJS side, do I only need to include the Pusher javascript file and declare the channel and work or is there something else I can do.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! for anyone out there who has problems setting up Pusher with Laravel, here are the steps to follow:

- Add Pusher to laravel using composer (composer require
  pusher/pusher-php-server)
- Inside your .env file add:

  PUSHER_APP_ID=YOUR_APP_ID PUSHER_KEY=YOUR_APP_KEY
  PUSHER_SECRET=YOUR_APP_SECRET
- Set the broadcast driver to pusher:

  BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
- Inside config/Broadcasting.php

> ```
> 'pusher' => [
>   'driver' => 'pusher',
>   'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
>   'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
>   'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
>   'options' => [
>     'cluster' => 'eu',
>     'encrypted' => true
>    ],
> ],
> ```

- create an event that gonna be broadcastable

Answer (score 1):

Yes. if using Pusher you don't need include in to project other tools. Such as Socket.io, redis or any other comet servers.